# Is it possible to SQL Update using row and column numbers?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using jquery datables/jedtiable which passed back ROW and COLUMN number and new VALUE to be updated like below. This is POST'ed to another JSP page which has a JDBC connection to an sqlite DB.

NOTE: I don't want to specify the column name, Just a number based on the int POST'ed from my other page. Hopefully this makes my question clearer

Row, Value, Column

> 2 No 4

What is the SQL to update 'No' into row 2 column 4?

Update *******************

This is currently working with rowid, however I would still like to be able to use column by number.

```
     String value = request.getParameter("value");
     String row = request.getParameter("row_id");
     String column = request.getParameter("column");

UPDATE PROJECT SET DELIVERY_STREAM ='"+value+"' WHERE rowid = "+rowId+";
```

Comment: If you are going to downvote, please make a comment. I believe this to be a valid question, if you disagree please comment and perhaps I can improve it.

Comment: It seems to me there is something no quite right with your design if you have to pass column names around as well as row identifiers. Can you expand on the reasons for this? In your example you don't use the column name parameter.

Comment: @Tony I should have explained. I am using jquery datatables and jeditable which is constructed to work like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All SQL commands require column *names*, not numbers.

Furthermore, SQL tables do not have an inherent order where row numbers would make sense; records can be identified only by some unique field values.

So, strictly speaking, the answer to your question is "no".

---

To access columns by number, you need to know which column has which number so that you can map the number back to the corresponding name:

```java
String[] columnNames = new String[] {
    "NAME", "DELIVERY_STREAM", "NUMBER_OF_FEET", "RETICULATED", ...
};
int columnNumber = ...;

String sql = "UPDATE Project SET " + columnNames[columnNumber] + " = ? WHERE ...";
```

Mapping from row numbers to actual records would require that you store an array with those records' key values somewhere, but this is not feasible when using multiple JSP pages.
Instead of the row number, just use some key value from the original table (the primary key, or SQLite's `rowid`) to identify records; that is what keys are for.

Comment: Thanks, This was the closest, however I went for a different option and managed to have the jquery pass column name, which made things much easier

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that you have some unique order field (ord_field) in your table. Then you could do something close to this:

```
UPDATE table SET value ='some value'
FROM (
SELECT *, (select COUNT(0) 
            from table t1 
            where t2.ord_field <= t1.ord_field 
            ) AS ord
FROM table t2
ORDER BY ord_field ASC) a WHERE table.ord_field = a.ord_field AND a.ord BETTWEN 2 and 4
```

Comment: SQLite does not have `row_number`.