# PHP Mysql Update Table Row Without Column Name

Tags: php, arrays

I have a table that have 150 column.Now I want to update my row.

Suppose when I select my update form select box item type football.

Now in form I fill data.

No, I don't know the column name.But Know which number of column use.

Now how can I update without column name  ?

Answer (score 1):

For what I know you need to use the column name in SQL.

Here is a solution that might help you to solve your problem
[Is it possible to SQL Update using row and column numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183465/is-it-possible-to-sql-update-using-row-and-column-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Create an array that maps column numbers to names:

```
$cols = array('id', 'name', 'sport', ...);
```

Then when you're updating the row, you can do:

```
$col_name = $cols[$col_number];
$sql = "UPDATE yourTable SET `$col_name` = :value";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':value', $col_value);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Superb Answer. This user also done similar like you http://stackoverflow.com/a/15184651/1237175